# How do I remove rows with zero values in one specific column?

Tags: r

Let's say this is my data frame:

```
df                                              
     a   b  c   d   e   f   g   h   i j k l ll  m   n o p  q   r
1 Dxa8 Dxa8 0 Dxa8 Dxa8 0 Dxa8 Dxa8 0 0 0 0  0 0.00 0 0 0 Dxc8 0
2 Dxb8 Dxc8 0 Dxe8 Dxi8 0 tneg tpos 0 0 0 0  0 0.03 0 0 0 Dxi8 0
```

And I want rows where `m` is not zero. The resulting data frame should only have row 2.

Here's what I've tried:

```
nzg = df[, !apply(df$m == 0, 2,all)]  # dim(x) must have a positive length
nzg = df[,-df$m==0]  # undefined columns specified
```

As well as many variants. I'm sure it's really easy, I'm just rusty, and all the other examples are for more complex situations.

Comment: 1. You can specify `m != 0` directly; 2. Check the difference between: `df[, 2]` and `df[2, ]`

Comment: `df[df$m!=0, ]`